# Resizing controls in sync with window size

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Over the last couple of days I have been reading dozens of posts everywhere about this.
I have a couple of WPF forms which I want to have working with most resolutions, the problem with this is that the controls within the forms become misplaced or look bad when increased in size.

At the moment I am using Grids, these are OK and keep my controls mostly in place but they take a along time to do (I have about 15 apps) as well as only look similar to the original design e.g. a few of the controls still look stretched and design gets affected.

Heres an example of one of my grids

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="156*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="323*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="72" />
    <RowDefinition Height="49" />
    <RowDefinition Height="49" />
    <RowDefinition Height="43" />
    <RowDefinition Height="91" />
    <RowDefinition Height="90" />
    <RowDefinition Height="90" />
    <RowDefinition Height="92" />
    <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

What I am really looking for is a good layout and control to provide a decent UI, what other alternatives are there to resizing the contents of a window with it? I am even willing to move back into windows forms if there's a better way to do this as grids seem to restrict controls. I am literally looking for the exact same look as the app initially has when its loaded in its default resolution(approx 500x500) once increased.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I'd say take a look at [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms754152.aspx) classes and try to combine them to achieve what you want.

Comment: So what is wrong with your column and row definitions above? Obviously the non-star rows are going to stay the same height but everything else should scale. Is the problem with the contents of the cells? In that case you'd need to show their markup too.

Answer (score 0):

Your Columns and your last row are using star sizing, which will cause the cells to stretch to fill available space. Depending on the the value of HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment, on the controls (the default varies by control), they may stretch to fill all of the available space as well (or they may center, or stretch in one direction only).

I suspect the star sizing is unintentional, but it may well be what you want, just used in a different way. You may also find "Auto" sizing useful. There's an explanation of your sizing options for a Grid here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/01/14/wpf-silverlight-layout-controls.aspx#grid